# Euclidean distance for more than two datapoints

Tags: distance

I have n 3-dimensional vectors. Is there a way to find distance between all using euclidean distance?

Answer (score 3):

You can use sklearn's `euclidean_distances` function.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances

```
In [1]: from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: x = np.random.rand(10, 3)

In [4]: euclidean_distances(x)
```